# Include google map in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#

I am newbie on this website and I will really appreciate what ever help I can get. I am trying to develop a website for my company using MS visual Webdeveloper 2010 express using C#. I want to include a google map with a marker so when clients visit our website they can find us. I am ready to give any more information if needed.
Thanx

Comment: I'm not sure there's any need for the hostile reception and all the down-votes. Let's help the bloke to help himself, isn't that what SO is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Google Maps and get the map looking how you want (best to search so you get a 'pin') you can then click on the chain link icon at the top right of the screen and Google will very kindly generate HTML that you can use to embed the map on your page. You can customise it to some extent too.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only 1 map, you can just embed it.
More info here: http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=72644

It's not that hard

Answer (score -1):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple.html